# Posts text and image to pdf in react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, download, blogs, pdf-conversion

I'm trying to create a blog post website where anyone can post anything. And also any user can download any post in one click. So is it possible to implement a button for download whole specific post content except side menus and comment in react.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to give the user the ability to download a blog post (react component) as pdf.

Check out [this tutorial by Robin Wieruch](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-component-to-pdf/)

What you basically do is create a ref for your component and then convert it to a canvas with html2canvas npm package, then to image data.

The image data is added to a pdf with pdfjs npm package and downloaded.

See the link for details.